# How I can select a column where in another column I need a specific things

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark data frame. How I can select a column where in another column I need a specific things. suppose I have n columns. for 2 columns I have

```
A.  B.
a   b 
a   c
d   f
```

I want all column B. where column `A` is `a`. so

```
A.  B.
a   b 
a   c
```

Comment: use `df.filter("A='a'")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a simple `filter`:

```
df2 = df.filter("A = 'a'")
```

which comes in many flavours, such as

```
df2 = df.filter(df.A == 'a')
df2 = df.filter(df['A'] == 'a')
```

or

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df2 = df.filter(F.col('A') == 'a')
```

Comment: after that I can select B

Comment: You can select B using df2.B or df2['B'] @elham

Comment: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`workexperiences`.`location` = 'US')' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(`workexperiences`.`location` = 'US')' (array<string> and string).; line 1 pos 0;

Comment: @elham you are attempting to filter an array type column using a single string. You cannot compare an array with a string. If you want to filter the rows with array containing a certain string, you can do `df2 = df.filter("array_contains(workexperiences.location, 'US')")`